# Customizing the target at creating context sensitive JavaHelp with Tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

With `tex4ht` I created all the files needed for `javahelp` (to show the html pages and accessing specific pages for a context sensitive help).

I have to access these specific pages by a key. Unfortunately these keys (target) are generated by a sequential algorithm:

```
<mapID target="section-1" url="docu_dese1.html#x2-10001"></mapID>
...
<mapID target="subsection-5" url="docu_dese4.html#x5-60004"></mapID>
```

So when I change the order of some sections in latex all links in my software would be wrong!

I would like to put my own keys there und I also found the place where the target (key name) is generated.

javahelp.4ht:

```
\NewConfigure{mapIdTarget}{2}
\Configure{mapIdTarget}
   {\sectionType-\sectionId}
   {}
```

But I have no idea, what I could use instead of this. Is there any section property field, which I can write in latex and (ab)use in javahelp.4ht?

Or is there a chance to customize the file names (html; then I could parse the xml file and assign the targets dynamically)?

Comment: did you find a solution for that problem? The output files can be changed with the function `\NextFile{name.html}`.
For example: `\let\oldsection=\section \def\section#1{\NextFile{#1.html}\oldsection{#1}}`
But this do not change the target attribute :-(

Comment: I am not familiar with this feature but maybe the documentation can help you: http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn25.html#mn25-1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for `tex4ht`.
